# How to get the most frequent value in a table

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I use MS SQL Server 2010.
I have a table with a millions rows, something like this:

```
Number      |  SITE    |Events_Work |Events_Nonwork
----------  | -------- | ---------  | ------------
1234567     | 1508     | 1          |  4
1234567     | 8263     | 1          |  0
1234567890  | 1905     | 0          |  1
1234567890  | 1697     | 0          |  0
1234567890  | 1697     | 1          |  0
22222222    | 2151     | 2          |  2
22222222    | 1905     | 3          |  1
22222222    | 1575     | 0          |  0
22222222    | 1575     | 4          |  1
1234567     | 1475     | 0          |  0
1234567     | 1110     | 0          |  0
1234567     | 1508     | 0          |  0
```

And i should find most used SITE for every different Number based  on: SUM  of events at work time (Events_Work) and SUM  of evenets Non_work_time (Events_Nonwork).

Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2010** - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014 and 2016 - take your pick !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with tmp1 as (
  select Number, Site,  eventsw + eventsNW total
  from YourTable 
  group by Number, Site, eventsw + eventsNW
)
select Number, Site, max(total)
from tmp1 
group by Site, Number
```

If i understand your question well this should be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding sum of the two column for each site in each number and rank on it to get the top ranked sites for each number using window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        rank() over (
            partition by number order by s desc
            ) rnk
    from (
        select t.*,
            sum(coalesce(events_work, 0) + coalesce(events_nonwork, 0)) over (
                partition by number,
                site
                ) s
        from your_table t
        ) t
    ) t
where rnk = 1;
```